# How to get values from an array inside a loop?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have 3 events and each one has a different name, so I created an array with them, and then on my html I have a modal, inside a loop, and that modal needs to display those events names from the array, but when I print_r, it brings only the 1st one. My code below:

```
<?php 
$id; $title;
$limit = 4;
$e_name = array(
    'Event name',
    'Other event name',
    'Third event name'
);
for($i = 0; $i <= $limit; $i++) {
    $e_name = $e_name[$i];
?>
<h5><?php echo $e_name; ?></h5>
<?php } #end for ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you `print_r`? Also, you're overwriting the array with `$e_name = $e_name[$i];`

Comment: Your array only has 3 elements, why are you looping 5 times?

Comment: `$e_name = $e_name[$i];` ??

Comment: Sorry about print_r, I just had used it to see what the array was returning. Also, I was using $limit but after I put a count() for that array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're reusing the variable `$e_name`. It starts out as the array, but after you do

```
$e_name = $e_name[$i];
```

it now contains just the first string in the array. On the next iteration, `$e_name[1]` is the 2nd character of `$e_name`. And on future iterations, `$i` is longer than `$e_name`, so you set it to the empty string.

Use a different variable, and use `foreach` to simplify the code.

```
foreach ($e_name as $name) {
    ?>
    <h5><?php echo $name; ?></h5>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: does foreach count the arrays limit automatically?

Comment: Of course, how else could it work?

Comment: Sure, sorry, my question was obvious :) I replaced for with foreach, so much better! Thank you. I'm a designer with some php knowledge, so that's why you thought it's a "basic" question. To me, isn't "basic" at all.